# How to find a match in multiple array and array lookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that are in tables, i need to find a match in multiple array locations. If i'm looking for only one location i'm good, but if i need to find it in another location lets say, location!A6:J6 i get #value. Here my lookup.

```
=INDEX(location!A8:J8,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A10:J10,0)) 'this is cell B6 formula *works fine

=INDEX(location!A6:J6&location!A8:J8,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A4:J4&location!A10:J10,0)) 'Here is the issue.
```

[image: Formula]

[image: Table]

*Note: one of my table is upside down as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a concatenated or a nested formula. There are many ways to compose it but may be the *easiest* would be to combine many `INDEX/MATCH` combinations so that the result would be the one that matches the entry.

I will first describe the general method and then apply it to your case. You have a search formula that works correctly in one range, but you want to apply many searches in many ranges. There are two methods to achieve this in general:

**Method 1: Concatenation**

```
=IFERROR(search1, "") & IFERROR(search2, "") & IFERROR(search3, "")
```

Only the successful search will appear as a result of this concatenation. If non succeeds, result is blank. However, if many succeed, result will be their concatenation.

**Method 2: Nesting**

We can also `nest` the `IFERROR` statements. In general this is more complex to edit but it solves the problem of duplicate results.

```
=IFERROR(search1, IFERROR(search2, IFERROR(search3, "Not Found")))
```

I prefer Method 1 in your case since you *know* that your search wont have duplicate results.So we keep it simple and apply the concatenation method to your case:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(location!A6:J6,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A4:J4,0)), "") &
 IFERROR(INDEX(location!A8:J8,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A10:J10,0)), "")
```

With Method 2 the formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(location!A6:J6,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A4:J4,0)), IFERROR(INDEX(location!A8:J8,MATCH(W_D!A6,location!A10:J10,0)), "Not Found")
```